# How to generate electrical current from biological decomposition

Tags: energy, decay

I'm working on a project to generate and store small amounts of electrical current by means of decaying organic matter and would like to know:

a) Is it possible to generate electrical current from biological decomposition ("decay of organic matter") i.e as a result of the naturally occurring chemical reactions that result from decay?

b) If so, how can this be demonstrated in a lab?

I've found this article on the subject so far and am looking for more accessible information on the topic:

https://www.livescience.com/63569-gut-bacteria-produces-electricity.html

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and [edit] your question accordingly. In particular, please clarify and focus your question — the article you linked to (and the original research article) seems to answer part a) of your question. If you have some reason to doubt that result please elaborate on why in your post. If not, then convert part a) into a statement (and reference the original paper as evidence). Note: you can probably answer b) by reading the Methods of that paper. Thanks! 

Answer (score 1):

What I was looking for is called a "Microbial Fuel Cell":

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microbial_fuel_cell